# How to add a pair dictionary into another dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

i'm a python rookie and i'm trying to make an app that will asign players to 3 teams based on the score they have key-name, value-score.

The way i tought of doing it was to get the maximum key, value pair from my main dictionary and move it into another dictionary like so...

```
team_1 = {}
team_2 = {}
team_3 = {}

players = {'alex':1, 'ion':2, 'octav':3, 'cristi':4, 'miu':5, 'spiri':6, 'fane':7, 'vali':8, 'grasu':9, 'jhonny':10, 'lil':10}


for key, value in players.items():
    if not team_1:
        x = max(players.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        team_1.update(x)
```

Obviously this didn't work, it gave me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    echipa1.update(x)
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 6; 2 is required
```

I don't necesserly want to make it this way, if any of you has any ideea how to make it even differently, i'm all years.

Comment: Your condition on assigning players to teams bit unclear but you can do, `team_1[key] = value` to add a key, value pair to `team_1` dict.

Comment: I know how to add normaly, but i want to copy the key value pair with the biggest value and add it into team_1 for example

Comment: You'll have to give a bit more detail. You've only described what to do with the item with the largest score. What happens to the rest of the players? What is your algorithm for sorting the players in to N number of teams?

Comment: Do you want to find the highest scoring players and split them up evenly between the teams?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work by replacing

```
        x = max(players.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        team_1.update(x)
```

with

```
        name, score = max(players.items(), key=lambda p: p[1])
        team_1[name] = score
```

Alternatively, you can replace `team_1.update(x)` with `team_1.update((x,))`

I think the former solution is clearer. The latter works because one possible input to `update()` is a sequence of pairs. `x` is a pair, so it needs to be in a sequence to be the right shape.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: wow you are trully a life savior :D scotty this is what i wanted but i didn't knew what to search and how to use it since i'm a beginner, i'm sorry i wasn't too explicit.

Comment: @mwchase By the way, how do you pop this pair from players after we add it to team_1?